# Compilation failure [ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment on Mac OS M1

Tags: java, macos, maven, environment-variables

I switched from windows to MacBook Air which is having M1 chip. I installed java and added the environment variables in .zprofile as follows

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${PATH}"
```

But when I run `echo $JAVA_HOME`, I see the output as `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home` instead of `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_311.jdk/Contents/Home`. I am not able to check if variable is set to JDK or JRE.

From Intellij, when I run `mvn test clean`, error is shown as,

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< org.example:SampleProject >----------------------
[INFO] Building SampleProject 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ SampleProject ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (US-ASCII actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ SampleProject ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ SampleProject ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (US-ASCII actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/moengage/IdeaProjects/SampleProject/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ SampleProject ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding US-ASCII, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/moengage/IdeaProjects/SampleProject/target/test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.392 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-11-18T13:20:33+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project SampleProject: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

Note: I checked others' questions as well and none of them were helpful. Can someone please help me in resolving this.

Comment: Hi, can you pls share the output of this command "echo $(/usr/libexec/java_home)" from Mac Terminal

Comment: @VasanthSubramanian, as mentioned above, the output is `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`

Comment: I use IntelliJ in my Mac. I configure JDK in IntelliJ Project by navigating to File | Project Structure | Project Settings | Project.. can you please check whether you configured JDK here?

Comment: It is already set to `1.8 version 1.8.0_311`